# OnLoad and OnChange (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, forms, onload, onchange

```
function safe(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("select[name='sort']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("input[name='group']").attr("disabled", "disabled")
    } else {
        $("select[name='sort']").attr("disabled", false);
        $("input[name='group']").attr("disabled", false)
    }
}
$('input#safe').change(failsafe);
```

I have this function that I want to run onLoad as well as onChange, at the same time. Currently only onChange works, but onLoad, those fields remain enabled.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for, but if you were hoping to run the `safe()` code when the page loads, try this.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewNEc/

```
$(function() {

    function safe(){
        if( this.checked ){
            $("select[name='sort']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("input[name='group']").attr("disabled", "disabled")
        } else {
            $("select[name='sort']").attr("disabled", false);
            $("input[name='group']").attr("disabled", false)
        }
    }
    $('input#safe').change(safe).triggerHandler("change");

});
```

Uses `.triggerHandler()` to fire the handler without changing the state.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming here `safe` is the `failsafe` function you're referring to and it's just a posting mixup.  Instead of [`.is(':checked')`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) you can just use the [`.checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/checked) DOM property and make it very short, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('input#safe').change(function() {
    $("select[name='sort'], input[name='group']").attr("disabled", this.checked);
  }).change();
});
```

The [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) call at the end triggers the `change` event handler you just bound, so it also runs on load.